# Can openam define policy plugin to evaluate user's request payload

Tags: plugins, parameters, request, policy, openam

I'm new to [openam](https://forgerock.org/openam/) and successfully finished sample in Getting Started section which protects an apache httpd service using openam including defining policy plugin that can evaluate user's userName and length of userName.

My question is: can openam define policy plugin that can evaluate user's request payload? For example, the original user http request may be something like http://www.example.com:8080?param=123, then openam can define a policy plugin which will evaluate the value of the request parameter "param" which must be a number, otherwise, the request is unauthorized?

I didn't find any guide about this, can somebody help me? Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible, yes (by writing a custom policy condition implementation), but I wouldn't really advise to do this. Parameter validation is the application's (or WAF's) responsibility and not the PDP's (Policy Decision Point).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But our project is to protect a cloud service without touching that service. So we may need a proxy like solution to do the protection. As you've mentioned about custom policy condition in openam, I found some documents about this but I didn't find any example about validate request payload. Do you know any reference of guide about this?

Comment: I may have misread your initial post. Since the policy resource URLs defined in OpenAM are the request URIs accessed by end-users/clients, request payload is not really available when a policy agent is in use. If you want the request payload to be available during evaluation (using a custom policy condition), then you would need to manually collate all the request parameters into the environment map and send the policy evaluation request manually to OpenAM.

Comment: Thank you Peter, by "manually collect all the request parameters into the environment map and send the policy evaluation request manually to OpenAM" that you mentioned, could you please give me some example or any guide reference about how to do this? I didn't find any clue on the internet...